# java calling command in if statement after method returns

Tags: java, recursion

I have a method:

```
public long getAppropriatePMStyleId(Office office, KMLFolder kmlFolder) {
        Long id = null;
        KMLFolder folderForStyle = kmlFolder;
        if (kmlFolder.getParentKMLFolderId() != null) {
            folderForStyle = kmlFolderServiceImpl.find(kmlFolder.getParentKMLFolderId());
            getAppropriatePMStyleId(office, folderForStyle);
        } else { 
            id = Long.parseLong(folderForStyle.getId());
        }
        return id;
    }
```

I've observed with the debugger that the method works appropriately until it hits the else case.  When it does, the id of the kmlFolder that was passed in to the method is assigned in the debugger panel.  However, when I step into where the `return id` statement is highlighted, the app goes to the line `getAppropriatePMStyleId(office, folderForStyle);` and throws a null pointer.  The method is only called in one place in the app, so I don't think it's being called again from outside.  Is there some Java behavior I'm not understanding here?

Comment: `id =  getAppropriatePMStyleId(office, folderForStyle);` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `if` block, you make the recursive call, but you don't do anything with what it returns.  You eventually `return id;`, but `id` was initialized to `null`.

Perhaps you meant to return what the recursive call returns:

```
id = getAppropriatePMStyleId(office, folderForStyle);
```

so that `return id;` returns the proper ID.

Comment: I would also recommend changing the type of `id` from `Long` to `long`.  I see no reason why it needs to be the object, and that's just causing a bunch of boxing and unboxing with every recursion.